# Let be $g(x):= \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

$g(x):= \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt$, where $f(x) := \cases{1,\, \text{if}\, |x|\le 3 \\ 0, \text{if }3<|x|} \,.$

Determine the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

If $x\ge 0$ then

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x,& 0\le x \le 3,\\ 3,& x>3.\end{cases}$$

Why? For $0<x\le 3$ it is $\int_0^x1dt=x$ and for $x>3$ it is $\int_0^31dt+\int_3^x0dt.$